# request for inherited member from public base and private base is ambiguos

Tags: c++

I've found something really strange in c++. I was tinkering with templates and stuff to create an utility that will check for presence of a certain field in a traits_t template parameter and it seemed to work... in my head until I tried to compile it. Long problem short, there is struct that inherits from two other structs, both of them have a member of the same name but it is qualified with different access modifiers (one is public and the other is private). So if I were to access it I would have accessed the public one... At least this is what I thought. But it doesn't work. Enough of explanations, here is an example:

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct a {
public: // totally visible for super class
    static constexpr int member = 1;
};

struct b {
private: // this must be hidden for super class, I guess
    static constexpr int member = 2;
};

struct c : public a, public b {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << c::member << std::endl; // should've accessed a::member but it fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler is gcc11. I dunno why is it so. I can rename member to somewhat like _member to mitigate this problem but I'm too curious to know why it doesn't work

Comment: "should've accessed a::member" why?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: btw nothing really "works" before you compiled, tested and debugged it ;)

Comment: @273K request for member '...' is ambiguos

Comment: you should include the compiler error message in the quesiton.

Comment: `public`, `protected`, and `private` are **access** specifiers; they do not affect visibility. Both definitions of `member` are visible in the derived class; only one of them is accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected, because name lookup happens before access restrictions apply. In particular, ambiguity cannot be resolved by making one candidate private as you seem to expect.

You get expected output by qualifying the base class:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << c::a::member << std::endl; // does access a::member 
}
```

Comment: I suspected it but it seemed pretty logical that you cannot access or even see private member. Yep

Comment: @Pingas why "logical" ? You can see them but not access

Comment: By using private modifier I wanted to avoid ambiguity but it seems that it not enough. I guess, I'll have to mangle name of the private member

Comment: why would you want to see something you cannot access in the first place? That's odd. But, yeah, it doesn't have to be this way.

Comment: @Pingas because its there. (and because `private` does not mean that it cannot be accessed by any means. It only protects from accidental access)

Comment: Everything clear now